# My home directory is empty

Tags: server

[image: Ubuntu home `ls output]

I just downloaded Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. But when I am trying to see the directory content with `ls`, I can't find any files like (Downloads, picture, etc).

Should I create them manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is by design. The desktop environment you install will usually create those folders for you.

Since you have the server version installed (based on the tag used in the post), those folders will not be created.

The default folder structure and content of your home folder will be the same as the "skeleton" folder in `/etc/skel`, which is usually only the following three files `.bash_logout`, `.bashrc` and `.profile`.

Answer (score 3):

You tagged this as `server`, and if you installed the server version then yes, your home directory is empty by default.